# Convert from one long row to multiple rows and colums

Tags: excel

I have a Spreadsheet that I have copied from a website. It runs from "A" to "ADV".
I need to set it to not be the said 802 cells wide and convert it into rows and columns.

I need one sheet 20 columns wide and however many deep to get 800+

I have one sheet 800+ cells wide

I could do this line by line, but that would quite literally take forever and I do not have that kind of time. I am hoping someone can help me out here.

Answer (score 2):

In A3:

```
=OFFSET(A$1,0,20*(ROW()-3))
```

copied across to T3 and then A3:T3 copied down as far as required.

Comment: thank you so very much pnuts it would have taken me forever becasue i forgot about the =offset